# How to use Json data directly in Python Scripts?

Tags: json, python-3.x

How to use Json data directly in Python Scripts?

this is data in data.json :

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "minipool",
  "private_key_id": "69fca468aede4ee9a884a7bfe9410badc4a6624a",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nSbAlvZ+OeIuaAKr3/wlFNg==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "minipoolserver@minipool.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "109697528046689636846",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/minipoolserver%40minipool.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

The code that I use with the JSON file :

```
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('data.json',scope)

# it works perfectly
```

I want to put this JSON data directly in python scripts :

```
import json

# Data value get from data.json    

data = "{ 
          "type": "service_account",
          "project_id": "minipool",
          "private_key_id": "69fca468aede4ee9a884a7bfe9410badc4a6624a",
          "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nSbAlvZ+OeIuaAKr3/wlFNg==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
          "client_email": "minipoolserver@minipool.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
          "client_id": "109697528046689636846",
          "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
          "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
          "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
          "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/minipoolserver%40minipool.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
        }"

# I want to convert this data to JSON that can use Instead​​​ of data.json

datajson = json.dumps(data)

# I want to use this datajson value Instead data.json but it gets an error

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(datajson,scope)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is this 'from_json_keyfile_name', but if you want to load the json text to be a dict that you can use , you can load the file with json.load(file), i.e.:

```
with open('filepath', 'r') as fp:
    data = json.load(fp)
```

Then you can use that data as an oridanry dict.
Hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: it gets the error : TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not dict

Comment: For simple way we use path to get data from JSON file, Examaple1 : `a = ('jsonfilepath', 'do something')` `this jsonfilepath stand for file type .json`, but how can we use it without use jsonfilepath Example2 : `a = ('datajson', do something')` `this datajson stand for a data without file that we can use instead use json file from our directory`